# ListView ItemSource ObservableRangeCollection<> accessing Model ObservableRangeCollection<>

Tags: c#, android, xaml, listview, xamarin

I'm developing an .NET Xamarin App. I want to list all Products as `ItemTemplate` in the Grouped-`ListView` and `Invoice.Name` as Header. Currently I only get the `GroupHeaderTemplate` shown in my Grouped-`ListView`.

Model: Invoice.cs

```
public class Invoice : ObservableRangeCollection<Invoice>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public ObservableRangeCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Model: Products.cs

```
public class Product : ObservableRangeCollection<Product>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpireDate { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel: MainViewVM (creating fake data)

```
public ObservableRangeCollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
public MainViewVM()
{
    Invoices.Add(new Invoice { Name = "Test1", Company = new Company { Image = image }, Products = new ObservableRangeCollection<Product>() { new Product { Name = "ProductTest1", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now }, new Product { Name = "ProductTest2", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now } } });
    Invoices.Add(new Invoice { Name = "Test2", Company = new Company { Image = image }, Products = new ObservableRangeCollection<Product>() { new Product { Name = "ProductTest3", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now }, new Product { Name = "ProductTest4", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now } } });
}
```

View: MainViewVM (ListView)

```
<ListView
IsGroupingEnabled="True"
ItemsSource="{Binding Invoices}">
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Invoice">
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Image Source="{Binding Company.Image}" WidthRequest="66" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Product">
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: this may not be the root problem, but `Invoice : ObservableRangeCollection<Invoice>` seems like a circular class definition, unless you have an Invoice class in two different namespaces.

Comment: @Jason I need it somehow, otherwise my ListView is empty. I've changed it to    `Invoice : ObservableRangeCollection<Product>` but won't affect it.

Comment: if `Invoice` inherits `ObservableRangeCollection<Product>` then there is no need to have a `Products` property that does the same thing.

Comment: If I don't have it, my `ListView` is empty.

Comment: you need to look at the Xamarin samples for grouping.  Your data is not structured correctly

Comment: @Jason thanks for the tip. Somehow I was able to fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a constructor with : base. That fixed it for me.
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping

```
public Invoice(string name, Company company, ObservableRangeCollection<Product> products) : base(products)
        {
            Name = name;
            Company = company;
            Products = products;
        }
```